KEDA Events in Azure Kubernetes Service's Log Analytics
Is it possible to review KEDA Events via Log Analytics Kusto queries from an Azure Kubernetes Service deployment?
I'm looking for a way to flow the events listed at https://keda.sh/docs/2.15/reference/events/ to the embedded Log Analytics mechanism of Azure Kubernetes Service.

Yes, it is possible to review KEDA events via Log Analytics in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) by configuring the AKS cluster to send Kubernetes events to Azure Monitor. To capture KEDA-specific events, you can use Azure Monitor's Log Analytics Workspace and write Kusto queries to search for the KEDA events.
Follow the below steps-
Create a Log Analytics Workspace
az monitor log-analytics workspace create \ --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \ --workspace-name $WORKSPACE_NAME \ --location $LOCATION



Link the Log Analytics Workspace to your AKS cluster to enable monitoring. This will start collecting logs, including KEDA-related events.
WORKSPACE_ID=$(az monitor log-analytics workspace show \ --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \ --workspace-name $WORKSPACE_NAME \ --query id --output tsv)

az aks enable-addons --addons monitoring \ --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \ --name cluster1 \ --workspace-resource-id $WORKSPACE_ID


Install KEDA
helm repo add kedacore https://kedacore.github.io/charts
helm repo update
helm install keda kedacore/keda \ --namespace keda \ --create-namespace


verify the pods are up

Since monitoring addon is already enabled for your AKS cluster, which means the necessary telemetry data (including Kubernetes events) should already be flowing into your Log Analytics workspace.
Use Kusto Queries to Monitor KEDA Events
KubeEvents
| where Namespace == "keda"
| project TimeGenerated, ObjectKind, Name, Namespace, Computer, Message
| order by TimeGenerated desc


